# If Sheet1 A2 Matches Sheet2 B2 Copy A2 to sheet2 A2

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two reports with matching "reference numbers".

But one sheet has an order number and one doesn't.

I need help with a formula that basically says if the two reference numbers match copy order number. The reports don't have the same information in them and currently I am copying and pasting after doing a <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> of the ref.

I know I can use something similar to:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E6,'Zone Chart'!A:A,0)>1,1,""),"") & IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E6,'Zone Chart'!B:B,0)>1,2,""),"") & IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E6,'Zone Chart'!C:C,0)>1,3,""),"")
```

But that doesn't copy a field and paste it some where else.

[image: https://ibb.co/XkkzLM8]

Answer (score 2):

The `MATCH` function returns the position of a search term within a given range.  If you enter this formula in A2 on Sheet2:

```
=MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0)
```

It will return the position of `Sheet2!A2` within column B on Sheet1 if an exact match is found or a `#N/A` error if no match.  The `0` in the last arguement tells the function to find an exact match.

What you want is the value in column A of Sheet1 that is in the same position as the `MATCH` gave you.  If the match position was 8 you could get the value by entering:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,8)
```

and it will give you 182012119.  Instead of using a hard-coded `8` replace it with the `MATCH` formula so you get:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

That will still return a `#N/A` error if there's no match so you may want to cover the possibility by wrapping the whole formula in an `IFERROR` function to return something more meaningful like "Not found in Sheet1":

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0)),"Not found in Sheet1")
```

Comment: I work in LO Calc, and Calc takes forever to evaluate entire columns.  So I try to specify explicit ranges.  Even if they're padded with lots of spare expansion range, it's still way faster than whole column evaluation.  Not sure whether Excel has the same problem.  Good explanation.

Comment: While I can't quote a source, I think since Excel 2007 the calculation engine changed to using something like VBAs `INTERSECT(UsedRange, Column())` so evaluation is limited to a small range instead of all rows in a column.  Way faster than Excel 2003 was with whole column references.

Answer (score 0):

From your question title:

Sheet 2 cell a2 formula:

```
=if(B2=Sheet1!A2,Sheet1!A2,"")
```

From your images it looks like you want something like this:

Sheet2 cell A2 formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:B,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0),1)
```

Comment: So I think this is it but I am having problems.
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:B,MATCH(B28,active_orders_xls:Sheet2!B:B,0),1)
the issue I am having is it's not returning a value from sheet2. On sheet2 the ref# I need to match is B2 and if value matches I need it to take what's in A column and paste it into sheet 1 or active_orders_xls in A column. Does that make sense?

I also keep getting a sheet1 error. But this is the thing formula I think! and I am super appreciate of it!! At this point its a little beyond my skills :-/ 

https://ibb.co/Q6Yp1qG

Comment: pulling info onto sheet1 from sheet2, place this in cell A2 on sheet1:  =INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0),1)